# density of polynomials and non-analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know there exists smooth, but not analytic function. One thing confuse me is that since polynomial is dense in a compact interval, every smooth(and continuous) can be approximate by polynomials, which implies it can be represent by infinite series(If $f_{1},f_{2},...$ converge to $f$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(f_{i}-f_{i+1})$ equal to $f$). So why there exists smooth but non analytic function?

I know that domain is one important factor, analytic function require the infinite series converge in an open set, while compact interval is not open. But one can restrict the function in a open subset inside the interval. Moreover, uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, so if $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{i}x^{i}$ converge to $f(x)$ uniformly, this implies it also converge pointwise. So what's wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the basic difference that you’re overlooking is that the sequence of partial sums of a power series is tightly restricted: the constant term never changes, and indeed every coefficient is eventually stable (e.g. $1, 1+x, 1+x+x^2, \ldots$)..  This imposes a lot of structure on the convergence properties of the sequence, which makes concepts like “radius of convergence” meaningful.

Conversely, when you take away that structure and allow arbitrary sequences of polynomials that have no relation to one another (the coefficients may vary wildly from one term to the next), it opens up the ability to approximate a much richer family of functions, but you also lose the guarantees of analyticity that are afforded by the confined environment of a power series.

Answer (score 1):

Your smooth function, indeed any continuous function, can indeed be written as an infinite series in polynomials, converging uniformly on a closed interval.  But this is not the same thing as
a power series, so the sum does not have to be analytic.

Comment: So a function can be written as infinite series of polynomials but not a power series? Can you give an example?

Comment: [Bernstein polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) provide an explicit sequence of polynomial approximations for any continuous function on $[0,1]$.